# Como configurar o ambiente Django e manter as configurações?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

Olá, eu estou começando a aprender Django e bem parte do material ensina a Fazer a configuração do Ambiente com Virtualenv. Porém estou tendo imensas dificuldades de configurar o Sistema.

Primeiro, eu uso um Macbook Pro com OSX Sierra. Segundo, já fiz as instalações necessárias, o Homebrew, PIP, virtualenv. Porém os comandos do virtualenv não funcionam. Já tentei um MONTE de soluções da internet, mudando o PATH dos arquivos e etc, uma série de coisas mesmo. Em uma dessas vezes por algum motivo deu certo, mas foram tantas coisas que eu fiz que não sei exatamente o que fez funcionar. Porém quando eu fechei o terminal e o abri de novo tudo havia parado de funcionar.

Eu não sei o que faço, não sei como consigo configurar. Meu amigo que também possuí um computador com as mesmas configurações que o meu Conseguiu ter o ambiente rodando normalmente, não foi necessário nada além das instalações dos arquivos e tudo mais. Eu gostaria de saber o que posso fazer, pois eu inclusive Formatei o meu Mac para fazer a configuração do ambiente e ele continua apresentando problemas na hora de executar qualquer comando das dependencias instaladas.

Estou bastante frustado e irritado com a situação, se puderem me ajudar agradeço muito.

---

Bem, eu comecei com estes:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

`brew install python3`

`sudo -H easy_install pip`

`sudo -H pip install virtualenv`

`sudo -H pip install virutalenvwrapper`

Os comando tentados do Virtualenv foram:
`mkvirtualenv teste`
Que devolveu como resposta:
`-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found`

Comment: Quais comandos foram tentados?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Bem eu comecei com estes:
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew install python3

sudo -H easy_install pip

sudo -H pip install virtualenv

sudo -H pip install virutalenvwrapper
`

Os comando tentados do Virtualenv foram:
`mkvirtualenv teste`
Que devolveu como respsota:
`-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found`

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Eu gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de RESETAR todas as instalações e trocar de Nome de Arquivo e etc que fiz ate entao

Comment: Sempre dá pra começar do zero. Apagar os diretórios criados até então é sempre uma opção. Veja também minha resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou te dar os passos que fiz aqui:

1. Conferir se o `virtualenv` está funcionando.

   ```
   > virtualenv env
   ```

   Aqui criou um diretório `env` como esperado.
2. Instalar o Django

   ```
   > pip install Django
   ```
3. Conferir se você colocou a [configuração](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file) do `virtualenvwrapper` no `profile` (`~/.bashrc`)

   O arquivo `.bashrc` do seu diretório `home` deve ter as seguintes linhas:

   ```
   export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
   source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
   ```
4. Recarregar suas configurações

   No bash, execute:

   ```
   > source ~/.bashrc
   ```

   E depois, tente novamente:

   ```
   > mkvirtualenv teste
   ```

Comment: Apareceu isto: quando tentei Recarregar as configurações:
`/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
`

Comment: Você pode por favor executar esta linha novamente? `sudo pip install virutalenvwrapper`. Preciso do retorno dela (a mensagem inteira).

Answer (score 0):

Considere "jogar fora" o virtual env, é sério! A solução? [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#macos).
Para instalar vc tem duas opções:

**Graphical Installer**

- Faça download do instalador gráfico
- Duplo click no arquivo .dpkg e siga as instruções

**Instalação via linha de comando**

```
bash Anaconda3-4.3.1-MacOSX-x86_64.sh  (python 3.6)
bash Anaconda2-4.3.1-MacOSX-x86_64.sh  (python 2.7)
```

**Criando uma nova env**

```
conda create -n nome_da_env python=2.7  # Env com o python 2
conda create -n py36 python=3.6         # Env com o python 3
```

**Considerações:**

- Anaconda resolve varios problemas do venv, realmente funciona, voce pode instalar pacotes normalmente com o pip ou pelo proprio conda/anaconda.
- Anaconda tem problemas com o virtual-env, desinstale-o
- Este pacote resolve o problema em ISPs nos quais vc nao tem acesso o root, como o Dreamhost, uma vez, que ele instala versoes do python, independete do sistema.
- Como o anacoda vem como 'teracentos' pacotes, principalmente na área científica, algumas pessoas dizem que ele é pesado e que, em alguns casos, é um chanhão para matar um mosquito, mas isso é desconhecimento, para isso temos o miniconda.
- Anaconda é uma distribuição e conda é um gerenciador de ambinte/pacote.

**Conda: Myths and Misconceptions**

Finalmente, acho interessante dar uma olhada [nesse link](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/).

[Baixe o Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#macos).

Comment: Cara achei muito legal isto, parece realmente mais robusto do que o Python e aparentemente funcionar melhor em ambiente com Python. Acho que vou testa-lo.

Comment: Qual séria a versão a ser instalada pelo Python 3 ou Python 2. Ou os dois?

Comment: Com o Anaconda vc pode ter os 2 ambientes, então vc pode baixar a [essa versão](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.3.1-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg) e instalar o python 2 em uma env isolada.

Comment: Uma observação: Quando vc diz "mais robusto do que o Python", esta cometendo um equivoco, o anaconda é um gerenciador de pacotes do python, é um "amigo" do python. :-)

Comment: Eu escrevi errado, eu tenho conciencia do que ele é. Só não vi que tinha escrito isto, desculpe.

Comment: @JKFher considere dar o aceite na resposta. :-)