# Não consigo importar nenhum módulo do Python

Tags: python, python-requests, módulo-python

Quero importar o módulo `requests` do Python para um programa que estou fazendo, mas não para de dar o seguinte erro, assim que eu executo o programa:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Eu tenho a última versão do Python instalada (reinstalei direto do site oficial ontem) e já entrei com o comando `sudo pip install requests` no Terminal do meu MacOS para instalar o módulo. O módulo **já está instalado**.

Não sei se talvez eu precise colocar a pasta do módulo na mesma pasta do meu programa... Não sei onde achar a pasta do módulo, de qualquer forma.

Sou novato, então me desculpe pela ignorância.

Segue o código do meu programa.

```
import requests

#meu programa
```

E meu programa (o arquivo *.py*) está localizado direto na Mesa (Desktop) do meu Mac.

Onde está o meu erro?

Obrigado!

Comment: É provavel que vc tenha mais de um ambiente python e o pip esteja instalando em um diferente. Para se ver livre de problemas com gerenciamento de envs, considere instalar o anacoda. Para instalação no mac, [veja essa resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205643/7412), para complementar a introdução ao anaconda, [veja essa.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/223520/7412)

Comment: Concordo com o Sidon e, se o "anacoda" ou "anaconda" não der certo você pode experimentar o `virtualenv`.

Comment: Já tentou rodar `pip install request` sem `sudo` e ver se funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Fala Santos!
Cara, isso esta parecendo que o pip deve estar instalando na sua versão antiga do python.
Faz o seguinte. Tenta executar o comando passando a versão, dessa forma a baixo:

```
pip3.6 install requests
```

Pressuponho q seja a versão 3.6 que vc tem ai. Se não, troca ao numero para a versão correspondente.

Answer (score 0):

Santos, passei por uma dificuldade parecida um tempo atrás, pelo fato de possuir várias versões do Python distintas instalados em meu Mac.

Resolvi o problema em um script específico da seguinte forma:

`Observação: verifique se possui o módulo instalado com o comando:
$ pip list (python2)
$ pip3 list (python3+)`

Caso ele não apareça no `pip list`, possivelmente não está instalado, então dê o comando: `pip install <nomeModulo>` e certifique-se de que o módulo está instalado em sua máquina.

**1.** Dei um which python3, para verificar onde está localizado a pasta main do meu python3

`$ which python3`

Ele me retornou algo do tipo:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`

**2.** Então, declarei o caminho do interpretador no meu script Python

`#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`

PS.: Acima do `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

E meu problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

vou dar minha contribuição, porém com uma limitação, mas mesmo assim espero ajudar ! Como eu uso Macbook e necessito instalar os programas na versão python 3.8 que é compatível com o root-CERN, eu uso o `macports`. Primeiro, teste para saber se você tem alguma versão::

```
$ sudo port installed |  grep -i pandas
```

Caso não possua :

```
$ sudo port install py38-pandas
```

No lugar de pandas você pode colocar qualquer biblioteca  de interesse como tensorflow, keras, h5py e etc.

Answer (score 0):

No ***Linux, Mac OS X e outros sistemas POSIX***, use os comandos Python com versão em combinação com a opção -m para executar a cópia apropriada de pip

```
python2   -m pip install NOME DO PACOTE  # Python 2 padrão
python2.7 -m pip install NOME DO PACOTE  # especificamente Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install NOME DO PACOTE  # Python 3 padrão
python3.8 -m pip install NOME DO PACOTE  # especificamente Python 3.8
python3.9 -m pip install NOME DO PACOTE  # especificamente Python 3.9
```

Answer (score -4):

Fala Santos!, recentemente passei por um problema parecido, pois não consegui importar nenhum módulo python que estava instalada na minha máquina, utilizo windows e uso o visual studio code.
Este problema estava acontecendo pois, o interpretador da linguagem selecionada no vscode, estava na versão 3.9.7, e a versão do python instalada na minha máquina estava na versão 3.9.5, por esse motivo os módulos python da minha máquina não estavam sendo importados para o arquivo.
Espero ter ajudado!